# How to get Print to File to pick up the correct Date/Time?

Tags: printing

Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, when I use the Print to File function, the Date/time printed at the bottom of a page is completely wrong, reading 1970!

The system date, as shown from the command line with the "date" command is correct.

How can the correct Date/time be set for printing?

Comment: "Print to file" in what program?

Comment: Print to File from main menu of Firefox

Comment: Is your timezone correct? `cat /etc/timezone `

Comment: Yes, system date and time look fine.  Something is wrong with the Date/Time variable pick-up by CUPS?

Comment: I'm not asking for time and date...  Make sure your timezone (e.g France/Paris) is correct. AFAIN I don't think that CUPS has any effect on printing to a file...

Comment: I checked the timezone - it's correct.

Comment: That's the only think that I could think of, add the output of `ls -l /etc/localtime` and `timedatectl` to your question it might be helpful to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60680/discussion-between-joe-and-ravexina).